# Pure websockets vs AJAX for browser multiplayer turn-based game

Tags: javascript, ajax, websocket

I plan to develop browser multiplayer turn-based game (2-6 players per game). Server part planed to write on Java. I have to choose between websockets and AJAX for exchange data in game process. I'm wondering which is the better choice.
I thought to use websockets, because it is not critically to support old browsers for me and latest version of browser supports websockets. But I know about websockets problem with proxies and routers. How do you think these problems affect most users? And what is better way to reduce the impact of these problems: use secured websockets instead usual, run websockets server on another (not 80) port? Or it's better to use AJAX?
I know about such libraries as socket.io and sockJS. But it's interested about pure websockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go for secure WebSocket. This will work in almost all network enviroments. Mobile. Enterprise. Etc. The exception potentially being so-called Man-in-the-Middle proxies which can unwrap TLS, and then WebSocket will depend on the proxy supporting and allowing it.

Note that with AJAX alone you don't have a push channel. If you want push and go with Comet, that can have it's own issues with proxies also.

Answer (score 1):

WebSocket is a persistent bidirectional connection. AJAX is just request-response. For a game, websockets make more sense. WSS should go through proxies, routers should not be a problem for either WS or WSS. However, some proxies are not friendly to persistent connections and could cut it after a while, there is no workaround for that.

Comment: Is this possible to figure out that proxy cut connection from client side?

Comment: If you are in control of the proxy, probably you can update to a websocket aware version. It  depends on the proxy software.

Comment: Not all the proxies cut websockets. There is nothing you can do from the client but try another port if it is a transparent proxy.